# Generic chceck in the stream collect java

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

```
List<String> namesOfMaleMembersCollect = roster
        .stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE)
        .map(p -> p.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I've got such a code, where `roster` is defined as `List<Person>`. In which place JVM checks if the returned List consist Strings? I mean we've got the List defined, but then there is no information about the String of retiring value. Is this:

```
.map(p -> p.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the place where JVM see that `.map()` getting String and know that the type of the list returned by `.collect()` will be same?

Comment: **Never**. The JVM will never check whether the generic types are correct. That’s handled at compile-time and is also the reason why performing *unchecked* operations can cause a collection to contain objects of wrong type if you do it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)  is a powerful tool that comes with `generics`. When you call `.map(p -> p.getName())` it returns a `Stream<String>`, now the the Stream has type parameter String instead of `T`.

Now you call collect which takes a Collector of the following signature.

```
 <R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)
```

And in the case `Stream<String>` it will be infered to

```
Collector<String, ?, List<String>>
```

Giving us `List<String>`

You can rewrite your code to the following

```
Collector<String, ?, List<String>> collector = Collectors.toList();

...map(p -> p.getName())
    .collect(collector);
```

Meaning the type is infered from the type of the variable the result is being assigned to.

Comment: Could you explain me how exactly generics work here? I mean, I don't get the signature of a method. There is `<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)`. Why we put in first diamond only R and A but we do not use T? What does give us this first diamond? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The map method return a stream of the result of applying the function in parameter so this return to you a stream of string and then we collect the result as a List using the collector.

In this cas its in this map function :

```
map(p -> p.getName())
```

it can be written like this (:

```
map(Person p -> {return p.getName();})
```